# Remove Blank Line In Between Select Queries When Spooling to CSV File 2

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I have query that is executed from SQLPLUS (11.2.0.4) and output is spooled to file. I am getting output file empty lines after each line + many empty spaces after the last column in the query. I have opened the file in notepad++ and i can see tons of empty spaces appended to the last column and ended with CRLF ( windows) , the last column is varchar 4000.

I have read tons of articles related to the same in internet but none of them help me. I have tried to set trimspool ON/OFF, trimout ON/OFF (btw - both commands are skipped ), page 0, heading off, pagesize 0, page 0, space 0, newpage nono

Example of SQL :

```
set termout off
set pagesize 0
set termout off
set pagesize 0
set heading off
set feedback off
set newpage none
set space 0
set linesize 8000
set longchunksize 200000 
/*above was tried step by step - no help*/

spool "G:/gggg/fffff.csv"
PROMT COL1|COL2|COL3

select col1||';'||col2||';'||nvl(col3,'') abc
FROM transactions;
spool off;

output (notepad++):
COL1|COL2|COL3CRLF
col1|col2|col3                                                              CRLF
col1|col2|col3                                                              CRLF
col1|col2|col3                                                              CRLF

output(linux)
COL1|COL2|COL3$
col1|col2|$
COL3      $

col1|col2|$
COL3      $

col1|col2|$
COL3      $
```

1. I have to use SQLPLUS .
2. it is requested to have output file without double quotes and with tilda as delimiter
   e.g.

```
aaaa~bbbb~cccc~eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
dddd~rrrr~bggggggg~rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
eeee~rrrrrrr~ttttttt~yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

Columns type :

```
col1 integer
col2 varchar2(4000 BYTE)
col3 varchar2(4000 BYTE)
```

Current output looks like

```
COL1NAME~COL2NAME~COL3NAME
aaaa~bbbb~cccc~eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee

dddd~rrrr~bggggggg~rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr

eeee~rrrrrrr~ttttttt~yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

I would like to remove the empty lines without any cut of the characters in lines.

I can see in notepad++ :

```
COL1NAME~COL2NAME~COL3NAMECRLF
aaaa~bbbb~cccc~eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee..................................CRLF
dddd~rrrr~bggggggg~rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr..............................CRLF
eeee~rrrrrrr~ttttttt~yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy............................CRLF
```

I can see in linux (after less) :

```
COL1NAME~COL2NAME~COL3NAME$
aaaa~bbbb~cccc~eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee$
eeeeee                             $
                                   $
dddd~rrrr~bggggggg~rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr$
rrrrrrrrrr                         $
                                   $
eeee~rrrrrrr~ttttttt~yyyyyyyyyyyyyy$
yyyyyyyyyyyy                       $
                                   $
```

Comment: Hi,

I have found the right solution for me :
```
SET HEADING OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET NEWPAGE NONE
SET SPACE 0
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET LINESIZE 32000
```
Note1: SQLPLUS recognizes trimspool , SQL Developer doesn't.

Note2 : coalesce(col2,'') doesn't work, it return always null value if col2 is null, i would expect empty string.

To get the right result I used :
```
CASE WHEN col2 is null or col2 = '' THEN '' ELSE col2 END
```

Comment: unfortunately, I wanted to put it as answer but from my account is not able put answer

Answer (score 0):

What's your table look like? Is COL3 defined as a CHAR or VARCHAR2? If a CHAR, that explains everything.

We need to see your data and your table, to be able to help you, otherwise you're asking us to guess.

Using the HR sample schema and the locations table, notice the varchar2's.

```
CREATE TABLE locations (
    location_id    NUMBER(4, 0),
    street_address VARCHAR2(40),
    postal_code    VARCHAR2(12),
    city           VARCHAR2(30)
        CONSTRAINT loc_city_nn NOT NULL ENABLE,
    state_province VARCHAR2(25),
    country_id     CHAR(2),
    CONSTRAINT loc_c_id_fk FOREIGN KEY ( country_id )
        REFERENCES hr.countries ( country_id )
    ENABLE
);
```

COUNTRY_ID is CHAR(2) - so you'll always see 2 spaces for that column, even if you only inserted '1' character.

Querying the table, with sqlformat set to CSV, I get CSV back, automatically.

SQLPlus 11.2.0.4 is approx from 2008, that's quite old.

Here's what you can do with [Oracle SQLcl](https://www.oracle.com/sqlcl) - smaller than SQLPlus, more powerful, and more user-friendly. Also, less code to get what you want.

```
SQLcl: Release 21.4 Production on Wed Feb 16 08:40:23 2022

Copyright (c) 1982, 2022, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Wed Feb 16 2022 08:40:24 -05:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0


login.sql found in the CWD. DB access is restricted for login.sql.
Adjust the SQLPATH to include the path to enable full functionality.
SQL> set pagesize 200
SQL> cd c:\users\jdsmith\desktop
SQL> spool peeps.csv
SQL> select * from locations;
"LOCATION_ID","STREET_ADDRESS","POSTAL_CODE","CITY","STATE_PROVINCE","COUNTRY_ID"
1000,"1297 Via Cola di Rie","00989","Roma","","IT"
1100,"93091 Calle della Testa","10934","Venice","","IT"
1200,"2017 Shinjuku-ku","1689","Tokyo","Tokyo Prefecture","JP"
1300,"9450 Kamiya-cho","6823","Hiroshima","","JP"
1400,"2014 Jabberwocky Rd","26192","Southlake","Texas","US"
1500,"2011 Interiors Blvd","99236","South San Francisco","California","US"
1600,"2007 Zagora St","50090","South Brunswick","New Jersey","US"
1700,"2004 Charade Rd","98199","Seattle","Washington","US"
1800,"147 Spadina Ave","M5V 2L7","Toronto","Ontario","CA"
1900,"6092 Boxwood St","YSW 9T2","Whitehorse","Yukon","CA"
2000,"40-5-12 Laogianggen","190518","Beijing","","CN"
2100,"1298 Vileparle (E)","490231","Bombay","Maharashtra","IN"
2200,"12-98 Victoria Street","2901","Sydney","New South Wales","AU"
2300,"198 Clementi North","540198","Singapore","","SG"
2400,"8204 Arthur St","","London","","UK"
2500,"Magdalen Centre, The Oxford Science Park","OX9 9ZB","Oxford","Oxford","UK"
2600,"9702 Chester Road","09629850293","Stretford","Manchester","UK"
2700,"Schwanthalerstr. 7031","80925","Munich","Bavaria","DE"
2800,"Rua Frei Caneca 1360 ","01307-002","Sao Paulo","Sao Paulo","BR"
2900,"20 Rue des Corps-Saints","1730","Geneva","Geneve","CH"
3000,"Murtenstrasse 921","3095","Bern","BE","CH"
3100,"Pieter Breughelstraat 837","3029SK","Utrecht","Utrecht","NL"
3200,"Mariano Escobedo 9991","11932","Mexico City","Distrito Federal,","MX"

23 rows selected.

SQL> spool off
SQL>
```

And here's what that looks like -

[image]

If you can update your question with sample DDL and data, we can give you a better answer.

*Disclaimer: I'm a product manager at Oracle for our Database tools.*